# What's the impact of multiple imports from the same module?

Tags: javascript, webpack, import, ecmascript-6, babeljs

Is there an impact on performance when using `import` (esp. when transpiling using `babel`) multiple times for the same module?  What's the difference, in terms of performance, if any, between:

```
import { something } from 'myModule';
import { somethingElse } from 'myModule';
```

vs

```
import {
  something,
  somethingElse
} from 'myModule';
```

vs

```
import * from 'myModule';
```

vs

```
import myModule from 'myModule';
```

This last one would assume that what's exported would contain `something` and `somethingElse`

e.g.

```
export default {
  something,    // provided elsewhere
  somethingElse // provided elsewhere
};
```

Comment: The last one wouldn't import the whole module. It would import the default export only. Did you mean `import * as wholeModule from 'myModule';` ?

Comment: Right, sorry.  Will ammend my question.

Comment: What is important is to consider [three shaking](https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking) and only import parts of the module being used so webpack can recognize unused exports and not to add them in the bundle, I don't think splitting will not affect the final result or the speed of building (I think)

Comment: Yeah, this is the reason we prefer importing only what's needed.  But for a few reasons, I'd like to import each part in a separate `import`.  But obviously I don't want to do that if it is going to degrade performance noticeably.

Comment: *"But obviously I don't want to do that if it is going to degrade performance noticeably."* It shouldn't make a difference.